# Can anyone tell me about this old portrait of George Washington?

Tags: united-states, political-history, art, president, photograph

[image]I’ve searched online, and can’t seem to find this exact portrait of him. There are always differences in the ruffles, lips, nose, etc. Also, what type of print is this and roughly how old is it?

Comment: What can *you* tell us about it? That will help greatly.

Comment: I’m looking to purchase it from someone local to me. All I know is who it is. It’s definitely got some age, though I don’t know how much. The seller doesn’t know either. The backing is held in with several little nails driven in parallel to the backing. There aren’t any markings or symbols that would tie it to a certain maker.

Comment: From reverse image search, it seems it was sold on [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/george-washington-picture-Framed-/373310614801?nma=true&si=YZ2DV4l%252FOwLexivOW23bLzSc4pI%253D&orig_cvip=true&nordt=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557) this morning:

Comment: He’s actually holding it for me. I’m sure he just marked it sold to end it on there.

Comment: It looks to me to be a 19th century lithograph repro of a redrawing of a version of a  Gilbert Stuart painting, obliterating Stuart's nuanced struggle to cope with Washington's signs of age.

Comment: Thanks kimchi. That’s probably the case.